# create a transition when an inline-block div changes places because of page resize

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I'm trying to add some css3 design to my website.

I have two `div` elements that are positioned with the following css class:

```
.formDiv {
   vertical-align:top;
   padding-left:10px;
   display:inline-block;
}
```

with the following test code:

```
 <body>
    <div class="formDiv">TestA</div>
    <div class="formDiv">TestB</Div>
    ...
```

but using this code both divs are shown on the same x axis, on the same line.

when i resize the browser on the x-axis till there is no room for both divs, the 2nd div is lowered below the first div.

my question is, can I configure that the movement of the 2nd div to go below the 1st div will be in a transition animation ?

for example i want to configure that if i resize the browser window it will take 2 seconds for the 2nd div to move below the first div and it will happen in animation instead of just appearing there.

I tried adding the following to the div class

```
    -webkit-transition: all 1s linear;
```

but it seems that it doesn't do the job.

any ideas?

thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The kind of effect that you want can be achieved by CSS Media Queries.

Here, http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

This is the demo from the above link, http://css-tricks.com/examples/MediaQueriesSidebar/

Try resizing the window and see the change in the "Super Team" list. You can use it to create the effect you want.

Some more examples of media queries and responsive web design. Resize and see how it adapts to window size.

http://designshack.net/articles/css/20-amazing-examples-of-using-media-queries-for-responsive-web-design/

See this, http://jsfiddle.net/Mke7E/

Comment: No problem. Hope you got what you were looking for.

Comment: first of all thanks for letting me know about it. I will use it in my application. unfortunately it doesn't create animation transition between the states.

Comment: I guess it can. Check out the fiddle.

Comment: amazing!! thanks a lot! i changed the display instead of using margin. works!! thank you so much!!!